# Convert XML Function in SQL SERVER

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml, sql-server-2008, converters

I've an XML COlUMN and I need to retrieve a value from it using Convert(xml)

In the below Value of a column Billing, I'm able to get the value of CODE/Description but how do I get the value of PRICE Value.

```
<BILLING><PRICE Value="5.00" Code="500-1300">
<CODE>11301</CODE>
<DESCRIPTION>Poly_806677</DESCRIPTION></PRICE>
```

I'm looking to get the value 5.00

The Code that I'm using to get CODE Value is

```
CONVERT(xml, BillID).value('(/BILLING/PRICE/CODE)[1]','varchar(500)')
```

Can you please Advice with any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this.

```
DECLARE @xml AS XML

SET @xml = '<BILLING>
<PRICE Value="5.00" Code="500-1300">
<CODE>11301</CODE>
<DESCRIPTION>Poly_806677</DESCRIPTION></PRICE>
</BILLING>'

SELECT @xml.value('(/BILLING/PRICE/@Value)[1]', 'varchar(500)')
```

and below line give you code value.

```
SELECT @xml.value('(/BILLING/PRICE/@Code)[1]', 'varchar(500)')
```